# Cómo crear campo calculado en una vista de SQLServer 2016 según valores de otros campos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Estoy intentando crear una columna calculada en una vista de dos tablas pero condicionando las operaciones de cálculo según ciertos valores de las columnas,

En la sentencia que adjunto la columna calculada `[Importe]` debe ser el producto de la columna `[Cantidad Suministrada] * Precio * [GG] * [BI] * [Presupuesto de Adjudicación] / [Presupuesto Base de Licitación]` pero... si `[GG]` es nulo, `[GG]` debe tomar el valor **1** (lo mismo con `[BI]`).

Y si el campo `[Precios Unitarios]` es **true**, no debe realizar la multiplicación `[Presupuesto de Adjudicación] / [Presupuesto Base de Licitación]`.

La sentencia que tengo no me hace esas condiciones porque no sé, he probado creando variables y con la sentencia `CASE WHEN` pero me da errores de sintaxis y se complica bastante (y no sé si ese es el camino), gracias por anticipado, pongo la sentencia que tengo:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TBContratos.[Código Expediente], dbo.TBPedidos.[Código del suministro], dbo.TBPedidos.[Fecha de Recepción], dbo.TBPedidos.Reactivo, 
                  dbo.TBPedidos.[Cantidad Suministrada], dbo.TBPedidos.Precio, dbo.TBContratos.[Precios Unitarios], dbo.TBContratos.GG, dbo.TBContratos.BI, 
                  CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto de adjudicación] AS decimal(16, 4)) / CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto Base de Licitación] AS decimal(16, 4)) AS Baja, 
                  CAST(dbo.TBPedidos.[Cantidad Suministrada] * dbo.TBPedidos.Precio AS money) AS Importe, dbo.TBPedidos.ETAP
FROM     dbo.TBContratos INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TBPedidos ON dbo.TBPedidos.[Código Expediente] = dbo.TBContratos.[Código Expediente]
WHERE  (dbo.TBPedidos.[Fecha de Recepción] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY dbo.TBPedidos.[Fecha de Recepción]
```

Answer (score 0):

lo conseguí con CASE WHEN, ahí lo dejo:

```sql
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TBContratos.[Código Expediente], dbo.TBPedidos.[Código del suministro], dbo.TBPedidos.[Fecha de Recepción], dbo.TBPedidos.Reactivo, 
                  dbo.TBPedidos.[Cantidad Suministrada], dbo.TBReactivos.Unidades, dbo.TBPedidos.Precio, dbo.TBContratos.[Precios Unitarios], dbo.TBContratos.GG, dbo.TBContratos.BI, 
                  CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto de adjudicación] AS decimal(16, 4)) / CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto Base de Licitación] AS decimal(16, 4)) AS Baja, 
                  CAST((dbo.TBPedidos.[Cantidad Suministrada] * dbo.TBPedidos.Precio) * (1 + CASE WHEN dbo.TBContratos.GG IS NULL 
                  THEN 0 ELSE dbo.TBContratos.GG / 100 END + CASE WHEN dbo.TBContratos.BI IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE dbo.TBContratos.BI / 100 END) 
                  * CASE WHEN dbo.TBContratos.[Precios Unitarios] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto de adjudicación] AS decimal(16, 4)) 
                  / CAST(dbo.TBContratos.[Presupuesto Base de Licitación] AS decimal(16, 4)) END AS money) AS Importe, dbo.TBPedidos.ETAP, dbo.TBReactivos.Tipo
FROM     dbo.TBContratos INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TBPedidos ON dbo.TBPedidos.[Código Expediente] = dbo.TBContratos.[Código Expediente] INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TBReactivos ON dbo.TBPedidos.Reactivo = dbo.TBReactivos.Reactivo
WHERE  (dbo.TBPedidos.[Fecha de Recepción] IS NOT NULL)
```